# jumping through multiple loops in no specific order (C++)

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to run a code that compares two strings and counts how many consecutive letters in the second string are available in the first string.

Edit: example of how the function should work:

longest_letter_run("this_is_some_text", "ais_")
Should return a 7 because the longest letter run is "is_is_s"
a is not accounted for because the first line of text doesn't have an "a".

My issue is that after running and confirming that the following line of code is true, 
(1)

```
if (word[i] == match[j]){
```

I want to jump back to the next iteration in (2)

```
for (int i=0; i < word.size(); i++){
```

and keep doing so until the condition in (1) is false again, then i'd exit all the loops after that.

But I'm unsure how to do so. Some posts suggested using a flag or using goto, but I don't think that works in this case.

Here is what I have so far, which only counts appearances of letter in both strings (doesn't count consecutive letters yet)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;




int longest_letter_run(string word, string match){
    int iter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < word.size(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j <match.size(); j++){
            if (word[i] == match[j]){
                if (true){
                    ++iter;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do not ask how to fix your solution, ask what is proper solution for a problem or what is wrong with your solution. So please describe problem your code supposed to solve.

Comment: didin't get what it means by "how many consecutive letters in the second string are available in the first string."

Comment: Am assuming it's a string-search but which also returns the number of letters of the best match (if the full string was not found). EDIT: With the new information looks like my assumption was wrong.

Comment: If this question comes from one of those online quiz sites, note that your proposed solution is one of the slowest.  Imagine if both strings had a thousand characters --  that is a million iterations.

Comment: I just added an example of how the function should run @LearningMathematics

Comment: It's not clear whether or not you know what `break` and `continue` do.  Did you try those?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It will be very slow, but I'm not dealing with any strings with more than 50 characters. If you have a different approach, I'm more than happy to get some feedback.

Comment: @Wyck I know what break and continue do, but I don't think they help in this situation to get to the outer most loop.

Comment: @VoltStatic, break does exactly that, breaks the current cycle, by consequence it jumps to outer cycle in this case.

Comment: Maybe add a couple of comments in your code:  one that says `// When I get here...` 
 and another that says `// ...I'd like to jump to here`  That way it should be more clear for us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a side note. `if (true)` is pointless and can be removed.

To answer your question, if I understand you correctly, you can use a control variable. (as others have said, you can just use `break` instead of control) For example:

```
for (int i=0; i < word.size(); i++){
    bool matched = false;
    for (int j=0; j < match.size() && !matched; j++){
        if (word[i] == match[j]){
            matched = true;
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is more in line with what you want though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


int longest_letter_run( const std::string &word, const std::string &match ) {
    int max = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++ ) {
        int count = 0;
        int word_idx = i;
        for ( int j = 0; j < match.size() && word_idx < word.size(); ++j, ++word_idx, ++count ) {
            if ( word[word_idx] != match[j] ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        max = std::max( max, count );
    }
    return max;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << longest_letter_run( "apples", "pp" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << longest_letter_run( "appples", "p" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << longest_letter_run( "weird", "weirdness" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << longest_letter_run( "weirdweirdne", "weirdness" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << longest_letter_run( "weirdweirdweirdnessweirdne", "weirdness" ) << '\n';

    getchar();
}
```

With the output of

```
2
1
5
7
9
```

EDIT:

Okay, per your comment of:

> The only condition is that they need to be consecutive letters in "word" whose letters are also in "match". ordering on letters in "match" is unnecessary.

```
int longest_letter_run( const std::string &word, const std::string &match ) {
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( match.find( word[i] ) != std::string::npos )
            ++count;
        else {
            max = std::max( max, count );
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    max = std::max( max, count );
    return max;
}
```

This has an output of (with the same main as before):

```
2
3
5
12
26
```

Comment: If this behavior is the goal, won't just a `break;` statement instead of `matched = true;` be equivalent? `break` just stops the most inner loop (and only that loop).

Comment: ... Yes, that would be true ... I'm reworking the code right now and I'll update.

Comment: @VoltStatic Oh, so you just want to know how many letters of "word" appear in "match"? I'm not sure I'm quite understanding exactly what you are looking for ...

Comment: That is correct. The only condition is that they need to be consecutive letters in "word" whose letters are also in "match". ordering on letters in "match" is unnecessary.

Comment: @VoltStatic, does my update meet what you mean now?

Comment: Great help! Thank you for helping me understand the questions!

Answer (score 1):

how about using `break`? It would break only the inner loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < word.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j < match.size(); j++)
    {
        if (word[i] == match[j])
        {
            ++iter;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using complicated loop flow I suggest to use a function:

```
bool inner_loop(string word,string match) { 
     for (int j=0; j <match.size(); j++){
        if (word[i] == match[j]) return true;
     }
     return false;
}


int longest_letter_run(string word, string match){
    int iter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < word.size(); i++){
        if (inner_loop(word,match)) ++iter;
    }
    return iter;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
template<typename T, typename F>
size_t length_longest_sequence_maching(T&& c, F&& f) {
    size_t result = 0;
    szie_t currentLen = 0;
    for(const auto& x : c) {
       if (f(x)) { 
          result = std::max(result, ++currentLen);
       } else {
          currentLen = 0;
       }
    }
}

size_t length_longest_char_sequence(const std::string& s, const std::string& charSet)
{
    return length_longest_sequence_maching(s, 
        [](auto ch) { return std::string::npos != charSet.find(ch); });
}
```

Comment: Should the second parameter of the template function be type `F`, not `T`?